# Address overriding in paypal

Tags: cakephp, paypal

I have this scenario that i need to override shipping address of my buyer so i got this code in my PaypalIpnConfig.php file:

```
var $settings = array(
//more settings
  'address1'=>'test address st',
  'address2'=>'test address st 2',
  'country'=>'United States',
  'state'=>'Alaska',
  'city'=> 'Anchorage',
  'zip'=>'99501',
  'address_override' =>'1'
);
```

but after reloading my site, i get this warning:

```
Unable to process payment. Please contact the merchant as the shipping address provided by the merchant is invalid, and the merchant has requested that your order must be shipped to that address.
```

i checked some of the questions similar to my issue however i did not get the answer i neede

[How to send Shipping address to Paypal, when using Paypal IPN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733926/how-to-send-shipping-address-to-paypal-when-using-paypal-ipn)

[Paypal Address Override not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851698/paypal-address-override-not-working)

what could possibly be wrong?

Comment: Dont you have needed to have provided the address in the format 'address_city'. I think what you're supplying is a display override

https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNReference

Answer (score 2):

State must be given as a 2-character word.
So in your case it would be: 'state'=>'AL' or something

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables#id08A6HI0J0VU