# How to fill paypal shipping address autometically using php

Tags: php, paypal

I am collecting customer's billing and shipping address in my website form and trying to fill the shipping address autometically in paypal checkout page.

I did filling successfully of billing address but unable to fill shipping address. I am using paypal ipn script.

any help would be appreciated Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your question doesn't give enough details to give you specific corrections, but it sounds like what you need would already have been covered in this answer to a previous question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27806656/is-it-possible-to-send-shipping-address-to-paypal-standard/27808691#27808691

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to send shipping address to Paypal Standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27806656/is-it-possible-to-send-shipping-address-to-paypal-standard)

Answer (score 0):

Are you working with Express Checkout or Standard Payments?  Either way, you can include shipping address parameters in the payment request and then set address_override to 1 so that it uses whatever you pass as opposed to letting the user choose an address from their PayPal account.