# How to use paypal express checkout with SimpleCart?

Tags: javascript, paypal, simplecart

Does SimpleCart supports paypal express checkout ?
I need to  get shipping address from customers which is not supported in standard checkout by paypal.Please suggest any way of doing that without involving backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to use simpleCart for paypal express checkout with their [sendform](http://simplecartjs.org/documentation/simplecart-checkout-sendform) but it requires back end coding. You can send the post data from  the cart and use it for express checkout.

Typically you are able to get shipping address from customers with standard checkout. Whenever I have had someone checkout using standard it has always just included their shipping address in the PayPal transaction details.
[Is it possible to send shipping address to Paypal Standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27806656/is-it-possible-to-send-shipping-address-to-paypal-standard)